# How to fix font-src CSP in html when using localhost?

Tags: html, content-security-policy

I am using electron to make a desktop app, and when it tries to load fonts, I get this error:

```
Refused to load the font 'http://localhost:5173/@fs/C:/Users/username/source/repos/QueryBuilder/node_modules/@mdi/font/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf?v=7.2.96' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src http://localhost".
```

And I have this meta tag

```
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="default-src 'self'; connect-src https://data.global; font-src http://localhost; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"
/>
```

How can I fix it? The port number seems to be random, I didn't configure that, so I don't think hardcoding it is good.

Comment: Try to set a wildcard port number then to allow all ports: http://localhost:*

Answer (score 0):

Try localhost:* to accept any port.